# circuitikz: to[-o] doesn't work as expected

Tags: circuitikz

## Problem statement

Inside of a `circuitikz` environment, the `to` operation doesn't work as expected. In the example below there should be a dot inside the red circle just like inside the line right above it.

*Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?*

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[dotted] (-1,-0.5) rectangle (3.8,3);
    \draw (0,0) to[I=$I$]
          (0,2) to[R=$R_i$,-o]
          (4,2) to
          (5,2);
    \draw (5,2) to[R=$R_L$]
          (5,0) to[-o] % the enddot here isn't drawn
          (4,0) to
          (0,0);
    \draw[->] (1,1.5) -- node[right] {$U_0 = \mathrm{const}$} (1,0.5);
    \draw[->] (4,1.5) -- node[right] {$U_\mathrm{kl}$} (4,0.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea what is going on, but I did find a workaround:

```
to[short,-o]
```

`short` is just a straight line judging by the manual. Seems `-o` and the like doesn't work when there is 'nothing else' in the `to` path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[dotted] (-1,-0.5) rectangle (3.8,3);
    \draw (0,0) to[I=$I$]
          (0,2) to[R=$R_i$,-o]
          (4,2) to
          (5,2);
    \draw (5,2) to[R=$R_L$]
          (5,0) to[short,-o]
          (4,0) to
          (0,0);
    \draw[->] (1,1.5) -- node[right] {$U_0 = \mathrm{const}$} (1,0.5);
    \draw[->] (4,1.5) -- node[right] {$U_\mathrm{kl}$} (4,0.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This a very strange behaviour. Anyways, thank you very much for your quick and correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

The question is nearly four years old. But maybe this is a desired answer.

I think (like Torbjørn T. said) `to []` needs "something" in the `[]`, than it can process `o-o` (for example).

I would do it this way:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
      (-1, -.5) [dotted] rectangle (2.8, 3);%thank you for this, I didn't knew this
    \draw
      (0, 0) to [I = $I$, v = $U_0{\;=\;}\text{const}$] (0, 2)%{\;=\;}: double equals signs are somehow not allowed
             to [R = $R_i$] (3, 2) -- (5, 2)
             to [R = $R_L$] (5, 0) -- (0, 0)
      (3, 2) to [open, v^ = $U_{\text{kl}}$, o-o] (3, 0);%^: shifts the label on the other side of the arrow
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

I hope this helps you.