# Line joins not covering (miter)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have the following code of a voltage source connected to two resistors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (0,0) to[V=$U$] ++(0,2) to[R=$R_i$, -*] ++(2,0) to[short, i=$I$] ++(1,0) to[R=$R_u$] ++(0,-2) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) to[short] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

which creates the following schematics.

[image: picture of miter problem]

As you can see, the beginpoint and endpoint (lower left corner) do not connect properly. I tried to use `line join=miter` but with no succes. How to do it properly?

Comment: workaround : replace the end `...to[short] (0,0);` with `... -| (0,.1);`

Comment: why you use `line join=miter`? it works fine without this option (as expected). anyway, i cant reproduce your problem (with recent `circuitikz`).

Comment: @Zarko Did you look at the lower left corner?

Comment: @marmot: ups, i miss this, actually test your code without line join=miter. `to cycle` solve problem without it. (+1 for `cycle`)

Comment: @Zarko if you have a solution with `cycle` you could write an answer ?

Comment: Another solution is to always start and stop at a dot.

Comment: @Kpym, this was part of marmot original answer (now i see that he change answer and omit it)

Comment: You could also make the last coordinate `(-0.5pt,0)`, where 0.5pt is half the line width.

Comment: By the way, it's actually the `line cap` that influences the ends of the lines. `line cap=rect` fixes that corner, but messes up the rest of the diagram, so it isn't very useful.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple more variants:

```
\documentclass[multi=circuitikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (0,0) to[V=$U$,name=U] ++(0,2) 
  to[R=$R_i$, -*] ++(2,0) 
  to[short, i=$I$] ++(1,0) 
  to[R=$R_u$] ++(0,-2) 
  to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) 
  to[short] (0,0)
  to[short] (U.west);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (2,0) to[short,*-] (0,0)
  to[V=$U$] ++(0,2) 
  to[R=$R_i$, -*] ++(2,0) 
  to[short, i=$I$] ++(1,0) 
  to[R=$R_u$] ++(0,-2) 
  to[short,-*] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your first version use the same trick as @marmot's answer (overwrite the starting edge). Probably you could keep only the second one that is good (+1).

Comment: @Kpym - OTOH, my solution stops before overwriting the component itself (although it this case you can't tell the difference).

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. If you use `to[short] (U.east)` or `to[short] (0,1)` or `to[short] (0,0.1)` or `to[short] (U.west)` in any case you goes a little bit up to make the corner as it should be, no ?

Comment: @Kpym - Some components are have open centers, so it makes a difference.  (As it turned out, when I tested it with one, I discovered I had used the wrong side.)

Answer (score 6):

My first reaction was to tell you to use `cycle` but this does not work, as mentioned in section 5.10 of the `circuitikz` manual. The reason is, as explained a bit more below, that the path gets decomposed into subpaths such that you need to add `-.`. In situations in which the path does not get divided into subpaths, you should use `cycle`, but this does not work here, so you need to "help" Ti*k*Z doing the right thing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (0,0) to[V=$U$] ++(0,2) to[R=$R_i$, -*] ++(2,0) 
to[short, i=$I$] ++(1,0) to[R=$R_u$] ++(0,-2) to[short, -*] ++(-1,0) 
to[short,-.] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**NOTE ADDED**: As this has lead to some confusion, I'd like to add some information. The obvious puzzle is why `cycle` doesn't work. This is because he behavior of `to` changes in `circuitikz` when one uses certain keys. Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (0,0) to[->] ++(0,2) to ++(2,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (0,0) to[-*]  ++(0,2) to ++(2,0) -- cycle;
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw[line join=miter] (0,0) to[short,-*] ++(0,2) to ++(2,0) -- cycle;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the `cycle` key "does not work" in the last example. On the other hand, the arrow directives `->` in the first two examples had no effect. This is because `to` in connection with `short` (or other `circuitikz` directives) decomposed the path. To understand these things better, you may want to look through `pgfcircpath.tex`, where some of the definitions are made. (Comment: one also finds there

```
            \ifx\pgf@temp\pgf@circ@temp % if it has not a name
                    \pgfmathrandominteger{\pgf@circ@rand}{1000}{9999}
                    \ctikzset{bipole/name = #2\pgf@circ@rand} % create it
            \fi
```

I guess that at a given point someone may report some strange behavior because accidentally a wrong path got referenced, but perhaps I am missing something here.) In the vicinity of this block you'll find the path decomposition routines. Altogether, the simplest fix is to look at section 5.10 of the `circuitikz` manual, where it is suggested to use `-.`, to use what @Kpym suggested, or some of the tricks in [John Kormylo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430688/121799) (the ordering is random and I am not ranking one proposal over another here).

Comment: @marmot I did try cycle, but also with no success. The trick to overwrite the begin wire of the voltage source does the trick.

Comment: @marmot, i rewarded your answer for the use of `cycle`, but now you delete it use :-(

Comment: @Zarko with cycle the edge was deformed (check the history of the post).

Comment: @marmot, i check my test again ... and `cycle` doesn't work at all. it doesn't draw last segment of line or misplaced it completely. on first sight this seems to be a bug.

Comment: @Zarko No, it is not a bug. Technically, the path consists of several subpaths because of the various `to[...]` directives.

Comment: @marmot, you might have right, but then this is miss features. later i will look further in this. subpath is apparently not joined ...

Comment: @Zarko I added some more information to my answer.

Comment: Probably [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135527/121799) is related.