# Chasing a non-deterministic bug in LaTeX

Tags: xetex, debugging

I have a `latex` file that when processed repeated times (like a thousand times) -- in a very small number of the runs (1 or 2) `xelatex` will drop a very specific character `\emptyset` from the PDF file, as seen here:

[image]

These are repeated run, seconds apart, on the same machine, same environment, the log-files are completely the same. Till now I have only been able to verify it on ONE machine.

So far I have blamed it on some unavailability of the file system (for milliseconds) at the time of the run, but the fact that the only symbol missing is always the same `\emptyset` is very intriguing.

Is there a way to guarantee that `xetex` will place the character in the PDF file when it is supposed to?

It this more common that I think it should be?

Comment: is "that can't happen" an acceptable answer?

Comment: more seriously xetex doesn't touch the fonts, they are loaded by the xdvipdfmx dvi driver which xetex normally runs in quiet mode, to debug use the `--no-pdf` option to `xetex` to get an `xdv` file then run `xdvipdfmx` by hand with full debug tracing

Comment: are you using classic tfm math fonts or opentype math via `unicode-math`, either way what font is `\emptyset` being taken from?

Comment: Your machine is now Boring-complete. It's just trying procrastination.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I would hope that "that can't happen" would be an acceptable answer, but I am finding out not to be the case ... the font here is MathTimesPro II, in the format you know, Type 1, with the installation from Walter Schmidt.

Comment: well as I say I'd split up the xetex and xdvipdfmx runs and use `-vv`  option to `xdvipdfmx` so it is verbose in its logging

Comment: I'll try that. I have to set the framework to compare the files produced and let it run overnight, so this may take a while...I'll report back.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Until very recently I'd have agreed that this won't happen but I saw that in one case [random numbers were used to create unique labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430680/121799). There at a given point non-reproducable errors are expected to happen. I am not saying that this is related in any way, but it shows that using certain packages *could in principle* cause the unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @marmot I hope you missed something there, else this seems like very questionable practice to me. If in this case there is no such strange code at work, I guess that under normal conditions on earth it is very unlikely that a deterministic calculation machine does create random issues and the problem lies somewhere in the code (no [butterfly operation](https://www.xkcd.com/378/) assumed)

Comment: The spacing is different in the two cases, so imho already xetex is seeing the wrong font/tfm. You should add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` and use the `--recorder` option so that when it happens again you can check the fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer good catch